# hector_mapping set-up

Tags: slam, navigation, mapping, hector-slam, hector-mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From the tutorial (http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_slam/Tutorials/SettingUpForYourRobot) which launch file is to be edited?

hector_slam/hector_mapping/launch/mapping_default.launch

or other?

Also, from the tutorial the parameters are listed as value="base_frame", value="odom", etc.; but in the launch file (mapping_default.launch) the parameters are listed as value="$(arg base_frame)" and value="$(arg odom_frame)"...

Am I in the wrong file or is setting arguments and calling them vs. the examples published in the tutorial a change from ROS electric to ROS fuerte?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41191/hector_mapping-set-up/) by [TJump](https://answers.ros.org/users/2785/tjump/) on ROS Answers with karma: 160 on 2012-08-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The answer by jodafo sums up things pretty well. To add just a minor point: The [mapping_default.launch](http://code.google.com/p/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/source/browse/trunk/hector_slam/hector_mapping/launch/mapping_default.launch) file is an example launch file and has some parameters specified using the <[arg](http://ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/XML/arg)> tag to facilitate reuse. If your robot for example uses 'my_base_frame' as a base_frame and 'odom' as odom frame you can use the mapping_default.launch file like so in your launch file:

```
  <include file="$(find hector_mapping)/launch/mapping_default.launch">
    <arg name="base_frame" value="my_base_frame"/>
    <arg name="odom_frame" value="odom"/>  
  </include>
```

Of course, this is just optional. You can write your own launch file or specify parameters using a shorter form like [here](http://code.google.com/p/rosjava/source/browse/google_handheld_slam/launch/hector_mapping.launch?repo=google&r=8faae27a7b20ba5f99e0a932400c732eee2e4b16).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-08-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jondo](https://answers.ros.org/users/22518/jondo/) on 2015-05-22**:
Can you please update the broken Google Code links?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

probably you will get a more qualified answer from one of the Hector guys soon since stefan kohlbrecher is quite active here, but until then ill try :).

mapping_default.launch should be indeed the right launch file, and it seems like they changed it a little bit since they wrote the tutorial. so you can either change base and odom frame by changing

```
arg name="base_frame" default="base_footprint"
arg name="odom_frame" default="nav"
```

or by changing

```
param name="base_frame" value="$(arg base_frame)" 
param name="odom_frame" value="$(arg odom_frame)"
```

as described in the tutorial.

I am assuming you are providing the requiered tfs as described in the tutorial?

or are you planning to use the provided bag file or gazebo? in both cases it should work out of the box...

---

Originally posted by [jodafo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1732/jodafo/) with karma: 365 on 2012-08-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jondo](https://answers.ros.org/users/22518/jondo/) on 2015-05-22**:
Which "provided bag file" do you mean? I don't see one on that tutorial page.

**Comment by [jodafo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1732/jodafo/) on 2015-06-01**:
I was referring to http://wiki.ros.org/hector_slam/Tutorials/MappingUsingLoggedData